# How can i develop the ListView like Pinterest in Android?

Tags: android, android-listview

[image]

I am developing this application based on this:
 https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView

I am facing the problem: the height of images on the left side is too large and the height of right side images is small, then the left side only shows some images. actuall I get all images of left and right images. I don't know how to increse the heights of the left and right ListViews dynamically.

Does anyone have a sample or an idea?

Comment: I think you are looking for staggeredgridview https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid

Comment: If you are using https://github.com/vladexologija/PinterestListView then can you please share the code you are using for setting the adapter. Because there are separate adapter for left listview and right listview.